# Decrypting payment Id of integrated address

Tags: monerod, integrated-address

I am using [monero-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monero-nodejs) liberary for rpc calls. I generated an integrated address and made a payment to this address.

By splitting the integrated address, I could see the paymentId is **a33582a5a77c125b**.

But when I check payments of this address, I get nothing (empty object)

```
Wallet.getPayments(req.params.id)
```

Do I need any decoding on this paymentId? I can see the [tx](https://testnet.xmrchain.com/search?value=49887046eac53e0dc2c832b6c9af1dcf6df87d75f7a4683fa3b6569ebb9111cd) mined.

Comment: Integrated payment IDs are encrypted. I don't know how to decrypt it however, but some advanced users might help.

Comment: I think I should change the title :)

Comment: @knaccc If you can help?

Comment: The payment id is stored in the tx_extra part of the transaction. To decode it you need to extract it, and then XOR it with (8a*R||0x8d) where a is your private view key, R is the transaction public key (which is also in tx_extra), || means concatenation, and * means elliptic curve scalar multiplication. I'm not familiar with this library, it looks like the maintainer will need to add this functionality.

Comment: So everyone using this integrated address is using this complex maths to check if they received paymets correspoing to an integarted address?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Integrated addresses cause the payment id to be encrypted, and decryption requires the math that I've outlined. The library should eventually be handling this math for you, but it seems that this functionality has not been implemented yet. I see that you've taken the time to open an issue at the github repository for that library, so hopefully they will implement this.

Answer (score 0):

[MyMonero](https://github.com/mymonero) provides a useful JavaScript library ([`mymonero-core-js`](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js)) for dealing with this sort of thing.

Here is a code snippet that shows how to encrypt/decrypt a payment id using [this bit of code](https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-core-js/blob/92734c193a40b89d55822d62a2a49f39200e1e5e/cryptonote_utils/cryptonote_utils.js#L2557) from `mymonero-core-js`.

```
const mm = require('mymonero-core-js').monero_utils

const viewKey = mm.random_keypair()
const txKey = mm.random_keypair()
const paymentId = 'badc0ffeefabcafe'

const INTEGRATED_ID_SIZE = 8
const ENCRYPTED_PAYMENT_ID_TAIL = 0x8d

// If you have the private tx key and public view key
const pidKey = mm.cn_fast_hash(
  mm.generate_key_derivation(viewKey.pub, txKey.sec) +
  ENCRYPTED_PAYMENT_ID_TAIL.toString(16)
).slice(0, INTEGRATED_ID_SIZE * 2)

// If you have the private view key and public tx key
const pidKey2 = mm.cn_fast_hash(
  mm.generate_key_derivation(txKey.pub, viewKey.sec) +
  ENCRYPTED_PAYMENT_ID_TAIL.toString(16)
).slice(0, INTEGRATED_ID_SIZE * 2)

// Assert that the pidKeys are equal
console.log((pidKey === pidKey2)
  ? 'pidKeys are equal (expected)'
  : 'pidKeys are not equal (unexpected)')

// Encrypt Payment ID
const encryptedPaymentId = mm.hex_xor(paymentId, pidKey)
console.log('Encrypted: ' + encryptedPaymentId)

// Decrypt Payment ID
const decryptedPaymentId = mm.hex_xor(encryptedPaymentId, pidKey)
console.log('Decrypted: ' + decryptedPaymentId)

// Assert that the original and decrypted payment ids are equal
console.log((decryptedPaymentId === paymentId)
  ? 'Successful Decryption!'
  : 'Unsuccessful Decryption')
```

Should provide an output similar to:

```
pidKeys are equal (expected)
Encrypted: cfc3f2120b7db7c0
Decrypted: badc0ffeefabcafe
Successful Decryption!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But I can see I get the same payment Id that I provided. I have encrypted payment Id , and I wish to decrypt it. Also, both encrypted and decrypted keys are of same length. But encrypted payment id is 16 chars where normal Payment ids is 106 chars.

Comment: No, payment IDs are either 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters) or 8 bytes (in the case of integrated addresses). As you asked about integrated addresses, the payment ID would be 8 bytes (or 16 chars as hex). There is no case where "Payment ids is 106 chars", whether encrypted, integrated, whatever.